# Cannot add connection in virt-manager (KVM) in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I tried to add connection with default settings. I did reboot after installation of virt-manager, VirtualBox works, my account is member of `libvrtd` group. I'm getting this:

```
Unable to connect to libvirt.

internal error: Cannot find suitable emulator for x86_64

Would you still like to remember this connection?
```

Comment: Are you member of `libvirtd` group? Please add output of `groups` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert yes, I'm.